# splitting list of numbers on each sequence of numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, list, recursion

I have been working on this problem for a couple days now and I can not seem to get the exact result I am looking for.  I have simplified my question to just number based so that I can be as clear as possible on what exactly I am doing and what I want in return.

I start off with a big `List<List<double>>` where each sub `List` in the larger `List` contains 3 numbers. For example, the `List` looks something like this:

[0] 1,2,3

[1] 1,2,3

[2] 1,2,3

[3] 4,5,6

[4] 4,5,6

[5] 4,5,6

[6] 7,8,9

[7] 7,8,9

[8] 7,8,9

where each item in the list is a different sequence. What I am trying to accomplish is to separate the `List` into a group of smaller lists where each item in the list are all similar. So for the given example:

list1:

[0] 1,2,3

[1] 1,2,3

[2] 1,2,3

list 2:

[0] 4,5,6

[1] 4,5,6

[2] 4,5,6

list 3:

[0] 7,8,9

[1] 7,8,9

[2] 7,8,9

So, for solve my problem I have created a function to recursively search through the `List` and pull out the sequences that are similar and add them to separate lists.  Not only is my function not working, but my code is very long and complicated and I feel like there should be a similar solution than what I am trying to do.  Any suggestions or advice to get me going in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: "each list contains 3 numbers" <= What does this mean?  One-hundred-and-twenty-three is one number.  `123`.  Did you intend to actually have 3 numbers?  `1,2,3`?  Or is the range of numbers 100 - 999?

Comment: the latter: 1,2,3

Comment: In that case I don't understand the question.  Which is bigger?  `1,2,3` or `1,3,2`?  Why?

Comment: the order of the numbers does not matter, as long as the sequence contains the same numbers.

Comment: just a couple of small changes would modify your post in an example with real lists containing real values. This we could copy and paste and let it run. This would decrease our effort to helpt you and increase the velocity at which we can do so. You would have help much faster...

Comment: is `1,2,3` similar to `3,2,1` would they go into the same group ?

Comment: @MongZhu yes.  `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` would be in the same group.  `1,2,4` and `3,2,1` would be different groups

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed?

Comment: "yes. `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` would be in the same group" as you can see this is a vital information. You need to include this into your post. Otherwise you get answers that don't solve your problem accurately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it for you. It works with your 'out of order' requirement -- that is, {1,2,3} equals {3,2,1} equals {2,3,1}.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<double>> list = new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double>() { 1,2,3 },
        new List<double>() { 4,5,6 },
        new List<double>() { 7,8,9 },

        new List<double>() { 2,3,1 },
        new List<double>() { 5,6,4 },
        new List<double>() { 8,9,7 },

        new List<double>() { 3,1,2 },
        new List<double>() { 6,4,5 },
        new List<double>() { 9,7,8 },
    };

    // Pick a method, they both work
    //var q2 = DictionaryMethod(list);
    var q2 = LinqAggregateMethod(list);

    foreach (var item in q2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("List:");
        foreach (var item2 in item)
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{item2[0]}, {item2[1]}, {item2[2]}");
    }
}

static bool ListsAreEqual(List<double> x, List<double> y)
{
    foreach (var d in x.Distinct())
    {
        if (x.Count(i => i == d) != y.Count(i => i == d))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<List<double>>> LinqAggregateMethod(List<List<double>> list)
{
    var q = list.Aggregate(new List<List<double>>() /* accumulator(ret) initial value */, (ret, dlist) =>
    {
        // ret = accumulator
        // dlist = one of the List<double> from list

        // If accumulator doesn't already contain dlist (or it's equal), add it
        if (!ret.Any(dlistRet => ListsAreEqual(dlist, dlistRet)))
            ret.Add(dlist);
        return ret;
    });
    // At this point, q contains one 'version' of each list.

    // foreach item in q, select all the items in list where the lists are equal
    var q2 = q.Select(dlist => list.Where(item => ListsAreEqual(dlist, item)));
    return q2;
}

static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<List<double>>> DictionaryMethod(List<List<double>> list)
{
    var list2 = new Dictionary<List<double>, List<List<double>>>();
    // Loop over each List<double> in list
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        // Does the dictionary have a key that is equal to this item?
        var key = list2.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => ListsAreEqual(k, item));
        if (key == null)
        {
            // No key found, add it
            list2[item] = new List<List<double>>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Key was found, add item to its value
            list2[key].Add(item);
        }
    }
    var q2 = new List<List<List<double>>>();
    foreach (var key in list2.Keys)
    {
        var a = new List<List<double>>();
        a.Add(key); // Add the key
        a.AddRange(list2[key]); // Add the other lists
        q2.Add(a);
    }
    return q2;
}
```

Comment: bravo, the only working solution here :) have an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to this problem. I would divide it into 2 Steps.

```
// Sample input:
List<List<double>> lists = new List<List<double>>();
lists.Add(new List<double> { 1, 1, 3 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 1, 3, 1 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 3, 1, 1 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 4, 5, 6 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 4, 5, 6 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 6, 5, 4 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 7, 8, 9 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 8, 7, 9 });
lists.Add(new List<double> { 9, 8, 7 });
```

1) Get all unique lists from your collection. You can order them temporarily with `OrderBy`. This will allow a comparison using [SequenceEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<List<double>> uniqueOrdered = new List<List<double>>();

foreach (var element in lists.Select(x => x.OrderBy(y => y).ToList()))
{
    if (!uniqueOrdered.Any(x=> x.SequenceEqual(element)))
    {
        uniqueOrdered.Add(element);
    }
}
```

2) Now you have a set of representatives for each of your groups. Run through each representatives and get all lists that match the elements in your representative. Again here you can order them temporarily for the sake of comparison with `SequenceEqual`:

```
List<List<List<double>>> result = new List<List<List<double>>>();

foreach (var element in uniqueOrdered)
{
    result.Add(lists.FindAll(x=> x.OrderBy(t=>t).SequenceEqual(element)));
}
```

The lists in the resulting groups will maintain their original order!

Answer (score 0):

I tried my best to shorten the needed code to accomplish what I assume you want to accomplish. By the way I put the resulting lists in a list you'll see:

this following sample is just here to declare your list and put random values:

```
  List<List<int>> ContainerList = new List<List<int>>()
        {
            new List<int>()
            {
                0, 1, 2
            },
            new List<int>()
            {
                3, 4, 6
            },
            new List<int>()
            {
                0, 1, 2
            },
            new List<int>()
            {
                7, 8, 9
            },
        };
```

Now begins the payload:

```
        List<List<List<int>>> result = new List<List<List<int>>>();

        foreach (var cont in ContainerList)
            result.Add(ContainerList.FindAll(x => x.SequenceEqual(cont)));

        // the following erase duplicates
        result = result.Distinct().ToList();
```

So Now you can get your sublists as:

[0][0] 012

[0][1] 012

[1][0] 346
....

EXPLANATION:

```
 ContainerList.FindAll(x => x.SequenceEqual(cont))
```

The Following snippet use a predicate: the x here is a value in your list.

As it is a list of list, your x gonna be a list

SequenceEqual means that the Findall function will search equalities by VALUE and not by REFERENCE.

Next we erase duplicates because the Findall on the first element of the ContainerList will return a list containing all his duplicates correspounding to the given parameter (which is x).

But as the parameter (x) increments in the list. You gonna do as many FindAll as there are Values of the same subset. So in the example above, you gonna have 2 lists of 2 012;

I hope it is understandable. My english is terrible.

Comment: `SequenceEqual` does not recognize `1,2,3` and `3,2,1` as belonging to the same group unfortunately

Comment: also, the `Distinct` is not sufficient to remove the duplicates from the tripple list

Comment: It's true, i didn't see that the out of order was needed, by the way we can just change the sequence equal by a lambda that checks the first and the second sequence accordingly to the prerequisite. And for Distinct, a proper usage of Except should work fine. And it's far less complicated than other codes as it only needs  a very few lines

Comment: yeah `Distinct` needs an `IEqualityComparer` which has to be either implemented or use with a `HashSet<T>`. How would you get the unique items using `Except` ? I am curious

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I would use for the example that you gave.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<List<double>> lists = new List<List<double>>();
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 1, 2, 3 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 4, 5, 6 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 4, 5, 6 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 4, 5, 6 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 7, 8, 9 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 7, 8, 9 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 7, 8, 9 });
    lists.Add(new List<double> { 7, 8, 9 });

    List<List<List<double>>> sortedLists = new List<List<List<double>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; i++)
    {
        bool found = false;
        if (!(sortedLists.Count == 0))
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sortedLists.Count; j++)
            {
                if (lists[i][0] == sortedLists[j][0][0] && lists[i][1] == sortedLists[j][0][1] && lists[i][2] == sortedLists[j][0][2])
                {
                    found = true;
                    sortedLists[j].Add(lists[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            sortedLists.Add(new List<List<double>> { lists[i] });
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing is that the inner if statement is designed for this example specifically.

```
if (lists[i][0] == sortedLists[j][0][0] && lists[i][1] == sortedLists[j][0][1] && lists[i][2] == sortedLists[j][0][2])
```

This would have to be changed if you used anything out side of 3 double lists.

Comment: OP wrote this comment above: "yes. 1,2,3 and 3,2,1 would be in the same group" the if statement in your post cannot account for that. It shoves those numbers into different groups